What's the polite way for my library to return types from another crate?
I'm making a toy numerical crate, and some of my return types are complex numbers. I'm relying on num-complex under the hood, but my return types are also complex numbers. I considered simply returning tuples of f64 values, but that doesn't feel right.
If you were using a crate, how would you want to see this done? I hate to force anyone to include a dependency they don't want—even one as well-maintained as num-complex. Is it alright to pub use the complex type, or is there a more acceptable way?
Thanks for your time!

pub use num_complex::Complex64;
// and return a Complex64 value...

or
use num_complex::Complex64;
// and return a tuple of `f64`?


If they are using your library and you use a dependency, they are going to end up including that transitivity anyway. What value in hiding that are you trying to achieve?

Hiding the dependency can prevent the semver disaster.

This is called a "public dependency".
The proper way to handle this will be, in the future when RFC 3516 is stabilized, to mark the dependency as public = true in Cargo.toml.
In the meantime (and maybe after that too), you can (and should) re-export that dependency from your library:
pub extern crate num_complex;

Then, users can refer to it as your_library::num_complex.
